# How to determine success of MySQL transaction

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

In a regular single query statement to MySQL, I can use `mysql_affected_rows()==1` to determine whether or not something was updated. Now suppose I am trying to perform a transaction of the following:

```
USE myDB;
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE members SET member_active=0 WHERE member_id = 53;
UPDATE member_subscriptions SET subscription_active=0 WHERE member_id = 53;
COMMIT;
ROLLBACK;
```

Since I have those two update statements, should I could on a successful transaction being equivalent to `mysql_affected_rows()==2` ?

OR, is there a better way I should be checking for success?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you concerned with how many rows were affected, or with whether or not the transaction succeeded? They're two different things...

Comment: "is there a better way I should be checking for success" ? since you say they're different, how would you recommend I check for transaction success?

Comment: Again, is the important part that 1 row changed each time, or that `COMMIT` was executed properly?

Comment: that queries 1, 2, 3, n ALL completed -- the `COMMIT`

Comment: So it's okay if there's no member with an ID of 53?

Comment: at that point, i'd need to exit that transaction and start solving a different problem... then start over

Answer (score 1):

You should hold the value of `mysql_affected_rows` in variables. And total updation will be some of those variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you have track of both transactions and can have even better judgment which transaction is not performed and what would be the reaction.

```
USE myDB;
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE members SET member_active=0 WHERE member_id = 53;
$count1= mysql_affected_rows();
UPDATE member_subscriptions SET subscription_active=0 WHERE member_id = 53;
$count2= mysql_affected_rows();
COMMIT;
ROLLBACK;

$total_affected_rows = $count1 + $count2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes checking mysql_affected_rows()==2 is an alternative way from application level.

Its going to be 100% successful(`commit`) or nothing (`rolled back`) as you are using proper transactions.

EDIT: You can use `ROW_COUNT()` function in MySQL to get affected rows from last query as:

```
USE myDB;
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE members SET member_active=0 WHERE member_id = 53;
SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO @count1;
UPDATE member_subscriptions SET subscription_active=0 WHERE member_id = 53;
SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO @count2;
COMMIT;
ROLLBACK;
```

then the sum of these should be equals to 2

```
SELECT ((@count1 + @count2) = 2) AS status;
```